# Elasticity computation

Tags: regression, elasticity

Suppose that we have the following regression:

$$ln (h) = e_{0} + e_{1} ln (w) + u$$.

Isn't elasticity $e_{1}$? in other words: $\frac{\delta ln (h)}{\delta ln (w)}$? I am a bit confused since I have seen in some papers they take the first difference and then calculate elasticity, i.e.,
$\frac{\Delta ln (h)}{\Delta ln (w)}$ Which one is the correct way of calculating elasticity?

Comment: could you please link to concrete examples?

Comment: Suppose that we want to calculate the elasticity of labor supply. $h$ is the number of hours worked and $w$ is the wage. According to the standard definition, the estimated coefficient must be the elasticity, no?

Comment: the reason why I am asking is that you could calculate elasticity not just between level variables but also growth rates and your post might just have slightly incorrect notation, already your notation $\delta \ln(h)/\delta \ln(w)$ is non standard as in econ people would typically use $\partial \ln(h)/ \partial \ln(w)$ or $d \ln(h)/ d \ln(w)$, my best guess is that you just mistakenly $\Delta ln(h)/ \Delta ln(w)$ when the paper maybe said $d\Delta \ln(h)/ d\Delta \ln(w)$ which would be elasticity between growth rates or something like that. In that case taking first difference makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If you totally differentiate both the sides you will get:
$\frac{1}{h}d(h) = e_1 \frac{1}{w}d(w)$

$\Rightarrow e_1 = \frac{w}{h}\frac{d(h)}{d(w)} = \frac{\frac{d(h)}{h}}{\frac{d(w)}{w}} = \frac{\frac{d(h)}{h}*100}{\frac{d(w)}{w}*100} = \frac{\% \triangle h}{\% \triangle w} $

Which is the expression used to give elasticity of h with respect to w , hence $e_1$ is the elasticity.